# Rails 3 - Eager loading with conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Okay, I'm thoroughly stumped on this one. I'm trying to build a menu of published web pages organized by category.

Category.rb:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
has_many   :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
has_many :pages, :documents, :galleries
```

Page.rb

```
belongs_to :category
```

The Page model also has :is_published, so I'm trying to filter on that as well. I am reluctant to post my feeble query attempts, but see no other solution than to beg much smarter people:

(self is @current_website)

```
self.categories.includes(:children, :pages).where('pages.is_published = 1')
```

This returns mostly what I need, but not Parent Categories without published pages. For instance, it works great if I have:

```
Parent Category
- Published Page
- Child Category
-- Published Page
```

Where it fails is when I have no published pages in the parent, like this:

```
Parent Category
- Child Category
-- Published Page
- Child Category
-- Published Page
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this. I'm trying to learn as much as I can about queries, but I'm against the wall on this.

UPDATE: Implementing KandadaBoggu's suggestion has yielded much better results, this was added to Category.rb

```
  has_many :published_pages, :class_name => "Page",
                             :conditions => {:is_published => true}
```

However, when using the following:

```
self.categories.where(:parent_id => nil).includes({:children => :published_pages},
                                                   :published_pages)
```

I get the results I need, but I also get empty Parent Categories (no published_pages, no child categories with published pages. An example:

```
- Parent Category
-- Published Page
- Parent Category
-- NOTHING
```

My temporary fix was to appended the query with:

```
reject{|category| category.pages.empty? && category.children.empty?}
```

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a new association called `published_pages` (apart from your current associations)

```
class Category

  has_many   :children,        :class_name => "Category", 
               :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many   :published_pages, :class_name => "Page", 
               :conditions  => { :is_published => true }

end
```

Now you can get all the categories as follows:

```
self.categories.includes(:children, :published_pages)
```

If you are interested in learning why your approach didnt work, read the Rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) (scroll 10-15 lines after the `Eager loading of associations` section). I have included the relevant snippet below:

> For example
>
> ```
> Post.includes([:author, :comments]).where(['comments.approved = ?', true]).all
> ```
>
> This will result in a single SQL query with joins along the lines of:
>
> ```
> LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id and 
> LEFT OUTER JOIN authors  ON authors.id = posts.author_id.
> ```
>
> Note that using conditions like this can have unintended consequences.
>   In the above example posts with notion approved comments are not returned
>   at all, because the conditions apply to the SQL statement as a whole
>   and not just to the association. You must disambiguate column
>   references for this fallback to happen, for example :order =>
>   "author.name DESC" will work but :order => "name DESC" will not.

To eager load filtered rows of an association, use an association with conditions:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :approved_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', 
             :conditions => ['approved = ?', true]
end

Post.find(:all, :include => :approved_comments)
```

Comment: Thanks for the most excellent write-up, link and explanation, KandadaBoggu! This has certainly put me on the right path, I still have an issue with self.categories.includes(:children => :published_pages, :published_pages) delivering parents without pages or children categories with pages. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Update your question and specify your requirement w.r.t to presence/absence of pages.

Comment: This solution will not work when the condition is dynamic. In such cases, I use a workaround, which I have posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642900/eager-loading-the-right-way-to-do-things/12089216#12089216)